# can't get datatable.Select to return any rows

Tags: xml, vb.net, search, datatable

I have the following code that loads an XML file into a datatable (I went this route because I do not know how to query XML directly).  I want to use the Select method to return a row where "age = 72".  However, I can't seem to get this to work.  Any ideas?  Also, if there is a better way to search through a datatable for specifc values that would not require iterating through the whole table to get the results please let me know.

```
Imports System.Xml

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings
    settings.IgnoreWhitespace = True
    settings.IgnoreComments = True

    Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
    xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("..\..\XMLFile1.xml", settings)

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)

    dt = (ds.Tables("Age"))
    dt.TableName = "MainRMDTable"

    Dim dtValue() As DataRow
    Dim filter As String = "age = 72"
    dtValue = dt.Select(filter)

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

End Module
```

Update with the solution.

I needed to put single quotes around 72.

Comment: Can you show the content of XMLFile1.xml?

Comment: Steve, I think I figured it out.  I did not have single quotes arount 72 in my filter object.

Comment: Well, that's the reason I have asked to see your file. If age is a char field you need single quote around your value in filter string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit this page
http://zeusarticles.com/search-and-retrieve-data-xml-simply-using-vbnet-and-linq

This might be helpful.